# How to check that two python pathlib.Path have the same parents?

Tags: python, path, compare, parent, equality

With two `Path` objects that share the same parent paths, how do you compare them to assert that they do in fact share the same parents?

```py
>>> list(Path(input).parents)
[PosixPath('/usr/src/app'), PosixPath('/usr/src'), PosixPath('/usr'), PosixPath('/')]
>>> list(Path(output).parents)
[PosixPath('/usr/src/app'), PosixPath('/usr/src'), PosixPath('/usr'), PosixPath('/')]
>>> Path(input).parents == Path(output).parents
False

# huh?
```

Although the following works, it seems awkward to cast it to a `List`:

```py
>>> list(Path(input).parents) == list(Path(output).parents)
True
```

Comment: `parent` == `parent` works, fwiw

Answer (score 4):

`Path.parents` actually returns a helper object which enables indexed access and efficient iteration over the path elements (of type `pathlib._PathParents`). As a result your comparison is failing because it is trying to compare these two helper objects rather than their contents.

The docs are somewhat misleading in this sense:

> *Path.parents*: An immutable sequence providing access to the logical ancestors of the path

...to actually answer the question, you have options:

As pointed out in comments you can simply compare the parents:

```py
Path(input).parent == Path(output).parent
```

This works in many cases but will **not** match if the path isn't of the same form - i.e. when `..` appears in the path, or symlinks are present.

The `Path(...).samefile(...)` method provides a good way to avoid these issues, but be warned that using `Path(...).parent.samefile(...)` can still be a problem due to to `parent` calculation ignoring `..`.

Using the form `Path(...).resolve().parent.samefile(...)` is the most comprehensive way I've found of avoiding all of these issues.

For this particular question it would look like:

```py
Path(input).resolve().parent.samefile(Path(output).resolve().parent)
```